# Error using 'Join attributes by location' via Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, attribute-joins

Trying to run a simple script using `qgis:joinbylocation` but getting either errors or it's not processing correctly. I don't want to take a summary of the attributes, just the attributes of the first located feature and I want to keep all records. The *parameter selections* should be correct but it's the `sum,mean,min,max,median` that's causing problems. I tried removing them but python wasn't too happy. Also (for some reason) python doesn't recognise `mean` or `median` but is fine with the other statistical terms.

Any advice please?

```
##Test=name
##File_1=file
##File_2=file
##Output=output vector

mean=None
median=None

processing.runalg("qgis:joinbylocation", File_1, File_2, 0, sum,mean,min,max,median, 0, 1, Output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After typing the following into the Python console:

`import processing
 processing.alghelp("qgis:joinbylocation")`

You get this:

```
ALGORITHM: Join by location
INPUT1 <ParameterVector>
INPUT2 <ParameterVector>
SUMMARY <ParameterSelection>
STATS <ParameterString>
GEOMETRY <ParameterSelection>
KEEP <ParameterSelection>
OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

I failed to notice the `ParameterString` for `STATS` which basically means to add `'` on either side of the term  to convert it onto a string, like this: `'sum,mean,min,max,median'`.

So now the code is simply:

```
##Test=name
##File_1=file
##File_2=file
##Output=output vector

processing.runalg("qgis:joinbylocation", File_1, File_2, 0, '', 0, 1, Output)
```